# Anylogic - Events triggered by message

Tags: anylogic

i'm new to AnyLogic and i'm trying to built an ABM SIRS model for pertussis in Italy...but i'm stuck because I want infected agents to send a message to all the agents they are connected with.

I want the message to be an number ( [0,1] level of infectivity) and not a string and then the real problem is: once an agent gets this message it becomes infected with probability equal to the number in the message

Sending the message
[image]

Once the message is received
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

[image]

To understand, put your cursor into the "Expression" code box and hover over the little light bulb in the top left corner. 
Also refer to my blog on the little light bulb which can be a life-saver in these situations: [the magic lightbulb](http://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2016/2/4/the-magic-lightbulb-and-how-it-can-help-your-anylogic-modelling)

Comment: Thanks for your help!! It worked! :)  I think I got both the idea behind...and the importance of the lightbulb!  I gave a look at your blog too...it seems full of suggestions! My compliments!

Comment: good to hear. Please mark the question as resolved so others can benefit from this as well :-)